# How to marshal and unmarshal XML with irregular attributes

Tags: xml, go, attributes, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have an XML where different entities are represented with the same tag but with different attributes. Something like this:

```xml
<xml>
    <body>
        <Packet type="clients">
            <Row id="123" name="bill"/>
            <Row id="456" name="sasha"/>
        </Packet>
        <Packet type="orders">
            <Row sum="90" status="DONE" />
            <Row sum="190" status="DONE" />
       </Packet>
   </body>
</xml>
```

It is guaranteed that there would be only one packet with each type.

Unfortunately, it's not within my responsibility to change the structure of XML and I have to work with it as is. What would be the best way to deal with such structure in Go? Should I have one struct with all the possible attributes and just fill the right ones for each "packet"?

```golang
type XML struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"xml"`
    Body    struct {
        Packet []struct {
            Type string `xml:"type,attr"`
            Row  []struct {
                ID     string `xml:"id,attr"`
                Name   string `xml:"name,attr"`
                Sum    string `xml:"sum,attr"`
                Status string `xml:"status,attr"`
            } `xml:"Row"`
        } `xml:"Packet"`
    } `xml:"body"`
}
```

This seems doable, but quite inconvenient because in reality I have lots of different types of packets with loads of different attributes.

Or maybe there is the way to map the packets to different Go structs? Something like this:

```golang
type XML struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"xml"`
    Body    struct {
        ClientPacket struct {
            Type string `xml:"type,attr"`
            Row  []struct {
                ID   string `xml:"id,attr"`
                Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
            } `xml:"Row"` 
        } `xml:"Packet"` // ???
        OrderPacket struct {
            Type string `xml:"type,attr"`
            Row  []struct {
                Sum   string `xml:"sum,attr"`
                Status string `xml:"status,attr"`
            } `xml:"Row"` 
        } `xml:"Packet"` // ???
    } `xml:"body"`
}
```

The later seems like smarter and much more readable example, but I don't understand how to marshal and unmarshal xml with it.

Comment: you can try to "detect" the type of data you have and marshmallow it differently https://play.golang.org/p/kN-_1lLoggl

Comment: for marshaling I ended up using this library that gives all the control over resulting XML: https://github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter and separate structs for each "Packet" (but wrapped with the same interface). Conversion from structs into xmlwriter type can be done with or without reflection (for each struct).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways you can achieve this: You can try the approach you already described, with a struct containing all possible attributes. It would be tedious but easy. You can also try writing a custom unmarshaler for `Packet`:

```
type PacketXML struct {
   A *PacketTypeA
   B *PacketTypeB
   ...
}

func (x *PacketXML)  UnmarshalXML(d *Decoder, start StartElement) error {
    // Look at start attributes, find out what type of packet it has
    packetType:=findAttr(start,"type")
    switch packetType {
      case "typeA":
         x.A=&PacketTypeA{}
         return d.Decode(x.A)
      case "typeB":
         x.B=&PacketTypeB{}
         return d.Decode(x.B)
      ...
    }
  return nil
}
```

When everything is done, you can check which element of `PacketXML` instances are non-nill, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the file first (e.g. using XSLT) before marshalling.